# Firestore composite index not loading in console

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

```
firestore().collection("clinic").doc("+911111111111").collection("appointment")
        .where("dentistPhoneNumber","==","+911111111111")
        .where("timestamp", "<", end)
       .where("timestamp", ">", start).get()
```

Trying to create this index for firestore but link given out at terminal is not loading
[image]

Retried many times and tried loading it in incognito window too.

Any suggestion how to go about it ? Originally wanted to query whole collectionGroup of appointment but it gave the same error .

Comment: Have you tried to create it manually in the console?

Comment: @AlexMamo no I havent kinda gave up to filter timestamp from query and just doing it on client side